# SELECT Query with a Total at the Bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2012. The following query works great:

```
SELECT TOP 300 [ObjectID], [tbh_Objects].Title, [Quantity], [tbh_Section].Title
FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] 
INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] ON tbh_Objects.SectionID = tbh_Section.SectionID 
ORDER BY tbh_Objects.AddedDate DESC
```

I just want to do a **Total** at the end of the Quantity column keeping the same query. I read about Group By ROLL UP but it I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Do you want the quantity on a separate row or in a separate column?  Do you want the value only for 300 rows or for all the data?

Comment: You really need to add sample input and output data here.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want a Grand Total at the bottom of the Quantity column. It should sum up the Quantity of all 300 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GROUP BY and ROLL UP don't quite work that way I'm afraid.

What you're asking would be trivial in Excel, but to have a total at the end SQL needs to SUM, and to SUM it needs to remove all the duplicate lines that are part of the group, hence the GROUP BY.  However this defeats what you want, which is a balance at the end while *keeping* all the individual lines.

Something like the below will work without window functions, just to give you the idea.  However it won't scale very well so this is more along the lines of getting a quick fix.  Even for this it could do with another column to ensure the total always goes to the bottom.  The bigger this gets, either by number of rows or number of subtotals, the sooner I'd suggest moving to window functions and having the various totals unioned in at the end or displayed by application/report.

```
WITH cteIndividualLines AS
(
    SELECT TOP 300 [ObjectID], [tbh_Objects].Title, [Quantity], [tbh_Section].Title
    FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] 
    INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] ON tbh_Objects.SectionID = tbh_Section.SectionID 
    ORDER BY tbh_Objects.AddedDate DESC
),
cteGrandTotal AS
(
    SELECT
        GrandTotal = SUM(Quantity)
    FROM
        cteIndividualLines
)
SELECT
     ObjectID
    ,Title
    ,Quantity
    ,Title
FROM
    cteIndividualLines


UNION ALL


SELECT
     NULL
    ,'Grand Total'
    ,GrandTotal
    ,NULL
FROM
     cteGrandTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -> Sum with your detail query using a window function for the roll-up.

```
SELECT TOP 300 [ObjectID], [tbh_Objects].Title, [Quantity], [tbh_Section].Title,
SumQuantity = SUM([Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID)   
FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] 
INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] ON tbh_Objects.SectionID = tbh_Section.SectionID 
ORDER BY tbh_Objects.AddedDate DESC
```

If you need to keep the values aligned with what is in the TOP then this query should work out.

```
;WITH A AS
(
    SELECT [ObjectID], [tbh_Objects].Title, [Quantity], [tbh_Section].Title, 
    TopValue= ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tbh_Objects.AddedDate)
    FROM [ECom].[dbo].[tbh_Objects] 
    INNER JOIN [tbh_Section] ON tbh_Objects.SectionID = tbh_Section.SectionID
 ) 
 SELECT 
     *,
      SumQuantity = SUM([Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID) 
 FROM
     A
WHERE
    TopValue <= 300
```

Comment: The window function will operate independently of the TOP(X) selection, if that is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. I want a Grand Total at the bottom of the Quantity column. Just one row summing up Quantity of all 300 rows.